# Нажать на 1 строку DataGrid'a программно

Tags: c#, datagrid

Как сделать автоматическое нажатие на 1 поле ,чтобы было как 2 скрине
[[image: При загрузке]
[image: При нажатии]

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, какую технологию вы используете (Windows Forms или WPF), а так же паттерн, которого вы придерживаетесь

Comment: @LiptonDev Судя по скрину WPF, а паттерн, боюсь ошибиться, но вполне возможно его отсутствие